# trying to validate user input when exiting textbox in VB

Tags: vb.net, validation

I would think this problem is so simple and basic , I just can't get anything to work. I just want to validate user input and I can never get the validation rules to fire only when I want .  I've tried using got focus , lost focus , leave , and validating .  Some of those fire when the forms loaded some trigger when other fields look up .  There have to be an easy way I hope you can understand and can help. thanks

Comment: You need to mention what you are trying to validate.

Comment: [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) Class (see the example there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following txtName.TextChanged as the event, this will run each time the value is changed in the text box.

```
Private Sub txtName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtName.TextChanged

End Sub
```

Comment: i'm using textchanged but when set a value before the user gets to that textbox, it sets the textchangd off

Comment: So use a flag to enable and disable the event: clear the flag, set the initial value, set the flag. Then check the flag in your event handler; if it's clear, exit the handler.

Comment: Thanks Peter it believe and are not I started doing that and I thought that wasn't the way to handle this

Comment: You can handle it that way and there is no right and wrong answer to get this working. The TextChanged event is the best way to handle validation on value change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .net `ErrorProvider` and the `Validating` event.

```
Private err As New ErrorProvider()

Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        e.Cancel = True
        err.SetError(TextBox1, "This text box cannot be blank.")
    Else
        err.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback I started using the error provide it's working well

Comment: I'm still using a little bit of both tips.  I didn't know you can only select one that helped.  I set the error provider up on all my fields.  But the error provider would not allow me to leave a text box.  When the user puts in an invalid response I like to pop up a list box for them to choose the correct answer.  Error provider worked well for checking for zero numeric and blank entries.  I would clear the error to move to the list box.  But I find if I used lost focus I was having better luck.I'm a long time programming trying to move into the 21st century.thanks for the help

Comment: Not being able to leave the text box until you get the entry correct is a drawback. I feel your pain. I am 72 and can easily remember "What in the world would I use a class for" :-)